# Mismatch in the plot axis pyqtgraph, how ca I solve this

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I made a program that plots serial data using pyqt5 and pyqtgraph but suddenly the x and y axes seem to mismatch. I know the limits of my y axis so I use

```
self.ui.graphWidget.setYRange(-2500, 2500)
```

Even if I set them like this, the axis get to other values

[image: pyqtgraph error]

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/756#issuecomment-610288624) when you have two monitors, each with a different DPI. Luckily it has been solved in [PR 1509](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/1509). Take a look at the [HiDPI Displays section](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_use.html?highlight=mkqapp#hidpi-displays) of the documentation